# Prevent multiple buttons onclick triggers caused by identical buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have identical buttons. Problem is that on click listener:

```
$('button.cancel').on('click', function (event) {}
```

is triggered multiple times, based on the number of buttons I have (3 buttons - 3 times, 5 buttons - 5 times).

My intention is to get this listener executed only once per click.

Any way to prevent that, besides adding some classes or ids to the buttons themselves (it comes from the library widget, so editing is complicated)?

Comment: It should only be triggered once per click. Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Use stack snippets feature of the question editor to provide a live demo.

Comment: Add the html with the buttons to your question.